# How to fix the size of the container of the tooltip in materialize?

Tags: tooltip, materialize

How to fix the size of the container of the tooltip in materialize? 
 
I'd like width 200 always. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can have any specified fixed width for the tooltip containers by simply adding the following to your CSS:

```
.material-tooltip {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use max-width instead of width